# Kernel Graph problem

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, directed-graphs

as a homework project I received Kernel Graph problem, which is defined as:

Does $G$ possess a kernel, i.e. a subset $W$ of the nodes $V$ such that no two
nodes in $W$ are joined by an edge in $A$ and such that for each node $v$ in $V \setminus W$ there is a node $w$ in $W$ for which $(w, v)$ is an edge in $A$?

I would like to read about this problem, therefore I kindly ask you to suggest me some papers on this topic, or maybe different name of the problem, because I can't find much clear information about this problem.

Comment: You get quite relevant list of papers by googling "directed graph independent kernel" (without quotes), among others [this presentation](http://cermics.enpc.fr/~zhoua/slides/APassLaneau_062016.pdf) which looks like a decent starting point.

Comment: What is $A$? The  set of arcs of $G$?

Comment: This was helpfull. Still I cannot find proof which would stated that it is NP-complete problem. Every paper states it is indeed NP-complete problem and proof is in Chvatal's book "On  the  computational  complexity  of  finding  a  kernel", but the book is impossible to find in the internet.

@Mike I guess so

Comment: Searching for the paper with that title gives http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~chvatal/kernel.html which is a proof of NP-completeness.